# django: resolve variables in custom template

Tags: python, django, interpreter, django-templates

I'm making a custom template tag, and I want to be able to pass it in any sort of value. The use case is something like this:

```
{% include_with_args "path_to_template.html" simple_var an_object.foo.bar "A String" %}
```

When evaluating my custom template code, I want to evaluate `simple_var`, `an_object.foo.bar`, and `"A String"`, the same way Django would normally. Currently I have

```
these_args = [context[arg_name] for arg_name in self.arg_names]
```

However, this only works for variable names (`simple_var`).

How do I get my template to evaluate these strings just like Django would? That is, if `.foo` is a function that returns a dict with a `"bar"` key it should evaluate it as expected: `an_object.foo()["bar"]`.

In simple terms: I want to evaluate an expression to a value. How do I do that from a custom template?

Comment: This might be the point where I accept that i'm trying to put too much logic in the template, and go back to the views to try work out why it couldn't be done there.

Comment: I have a data structure like `{'Category1': {'Subcat1': obj, 'Subcat2': obj}, 'Category2': {'Subcat1': obj, 'Subcat4': obj}}` on an attribute of an object I pass to the template. Each `obj` is rendered with another template. So I want to do `{% include_with_args "obj_renderer.html" object.Category1.Subcat1 %}`, `{% include_with_args "obj_renderer.html" object.Category2.Subcat4 %}, etc... what would be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very simple. Instead of:

```
these_args = [context[arg_name] for arg_name in self.arg_names]
```

do:

```
these_args = [template.Variable(arg_name).resolve(context) for arg_name in self.arg_names]
```

Of course, now `arg_name` is a misnomer, so I changed that, but just wrote it this way to elucidate the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion tags already do what you want: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

The only thing you'd have to do slightly different is change where an_object.foo.bar gets called. Instead of doing that in the args of the tag at the template layer, you'd do it in the Python code of the tag.